# Swagger - Pattern for Base64 strings

Tags: base64, swagger, swagger-2.0

I have a swagger file where the `"pattern"` is `^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?$` and the default string needs to be `"Basic dXNlckBkb21haW4uY29tOnBhc3N3b3Jk"` (which is a Base64 encoded string with the word 'Basic' infront of it).

I am getting the error `"String does not match pattern`. I am not sure how to add the 'Basic' infront of the Base64 string. Tips?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using HTTP basic authentication for your REST API. I would suggest you to document that as "Security Scheme Object" instead. e.g.

```
{
  "type": "basic"
}
```

Ref: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#security-scheme-object